# UITableViewCell self sizing mess up

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am trying to make my UITableViewCell something like this:
[image]

I decide to add an UIView to contain my text so that I can make the border. This is my .xib config
[image]

My ViewController's TableView setup

```
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
        if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
            tableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = 0.0
        }
        self.tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

But things end up like this

[image]

Is it something about my constraints setup? Or I am missing something, can someone point it out?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a constraint between one of these two labels and the border view, which will make the height of the cell dynamic. These two labels are also center Y so you can make any of them have a bottom constraint with `BorderView`, i.e., I will do it with `AmountTypeLabel` and change the constraint bottom value to 10.

[image]

This is the output:

[image]

Just simple thinking about constraint from top to bottom with all subviews will make the cell have dynamic height:

```
ContentViewTop
      |
 BorderViewTop
      |
    Label
      |
 BorderViewBottom
      |
ContentViewBottom
```

Comment: it works, thank @son

Comment: You're very welcome.